# How to access the extended help mode in Julia?

Tags: julia

The Julia REPL comes with a default help mode which you can access by doing `?` in the terminal. However, I saw someone mention the `# Extended help` and how package developers can use that header to write longer doc strings which are hidden from the usual `?` help response. How do I access this extended help section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia's extended help section can be accessed by doing something like `??Print` rather than `?Print` in the REPL. Again, as aforementioned, this will display the extended examples section.

It is worth noting that not every function nor every package take advantage of this. It is best to check the source file's to see if the `# Extended help` feature is enabled for a particular package.